# ActionScript 3: Smooth programmatic animation

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to animate MoviveClips/Sprite objects as smootly as possible. However so far the only method that works is placing the movement code into the EnterFrame event handler. There is one problem with this approach: when the framerate on a specific machine is below the desired framerate then the whole game slows down. I want to be able to do this in a time-independent manner.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two ways to do programmatic animation within the Flash player. The first you already pointed out by using a onEnterFrame. However, as you might already have noticed, to get a smooth animation you need to increase the overall frame rate of your movie. Doing this will also increase the CPU load for the entire period of time your SWF runs. This is not something you always want.

The other way of doing programmatic animation is by using a timer. Within a timer handler it is possible to call a function named `updateAfterEvent` which will update the screen independent from the FPS you'd set for your SWF. Therefore, using a timer leaves a gateway to do smooth animation within the Flash player without increasing the overall frame rate of your SWF.

Two years ago or so I set out to create my own tween libraries for Flash (because of my frustrations with the then existing tween libraries available). I released it under the name [Coretween](http://www.coretween.org) and this library lets you, among other things, choose what type of animation you prefer for every individual tween. On the documentation page I give an [example](http://www.coretween.org/documentation.html#RenderMethod) of the difference between frame based and time based animation. The example SWF on that page runs at 12 fps but as you can see, the lower circle tweens much smoother because it's controlled by a timer that ticks at 60 fps and updates the screen in-depended from the SWF frame rate. Do keep in mind though that even the timer ticks at 60 fps in reality the Flash Player will never be able to achieve this frame rate. However, it will try to achieve this frame rate which results in a much smoother overall animation.

Unfortunately until now I've not been able to release a 1.0 version of my library but as far as I know it's pretty stable. You're more than welcome to use it in any way you see fit. I've used Coretween in many commercial productions including this one we did for [StGeorge](http://www.stgeorge.com.au/promos/yourhome/) bank here in Australia.

Comment: Awesome! Just what I need. I will wait with the accept, so you can get more upvotes:)

Comment: Thanks. People can still up-vote when a answers is accepted. :)

Comment: Questions with no accepted answers usually get more attention. Most of the users don't bother upvoting an answer after it gets accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few Actionscript based animation libraries:

[TweenMax](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.greensock.com%2Ftweenmaxas3%2F&ei=UzkhSpD8IYPBtwfCxOnBBg&rct=j&q=TweenMax&usg=AFQjCNFfJ41rVV8JX7vg8VfC2vRwuwzAkQ)

[Tweener](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Ftweener%2F&ei=eTkhSqT7COHgtgfS6uzABg&rct=j&q=Tweener&usg=AFQjCNH06RZesH0SEvPCYbJ-J0OMFd7GGQ)

They both work well, and should help you with what you need.

Comment: Unfortunately not, since I need real time smooth control over my objects. The tweener method, that guarantees that sometimes in the future the object will arrive to its desired position is "ungood".